# wilfly/java8 failed to start service

Tags: drools-guvnor

I have wildfly 9/java8 server box and trying to deploy drools Version 5.4.0.CR1.  Getting the following exception when trying to start the server.

2015-09-17 09:24:18,753 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."drools-guvnor.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."drools-guvnor.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000818: Event type class org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl is not allowed
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:222)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.checkEventObjectType(ObserverNotifier.java:215)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:152)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:692)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.fireEvent(ForwardingBeanManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.XmlConfigExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(XmlConfigExtension.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:92)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:45)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:368)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:92)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final.jar:1.2.6.Final]
... 3 more
```

Anyone have an idea??

Comment: Having same issue. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Drools-Guvnor-5.4.0-Final or 5.5.0-Final or 5.6.0-Final ???

I had issues in a Tomcat-8/JDK7 environment and had to test all point release versions of the Drools-Guvnor 5.x war to find the right war that would work reliably in my specific configuration.

Comment: This would better fit as a comment on the question, but if this answer worked for you, no need to ask if it worked.

Comment: A comment was more my intent.. thanks for the heads up.